# How to choose action in TD(0) learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I am currently reading Sutton's `Reinforcement Learning: An introduction` book. After reading chapter 6.1 I wanted to implement a `TD(0)` RL algorithm for this setting:

[image]
[image]

To do this, I tried to implement the pseudo-code presented here:
[image]

Doing this I wondered how to do this step `A <- action given by π for S`: I can I choose the optimal action `A` for my current state `S`? As the value function `V(S)` is just depending on the state and not on the action I do not really know, how this can be done.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884168/implementing-temporal-difference-learning-for-a-random-walk-in-python) question (where I got the images from) which deals with the same exercise - but here the action is just picked randomly and not choosen by an action policy `π`.

Edit: Or this is pseudo-code not complete, so that I have to approximate the `action-value function Q(s, a)` in another way, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, you cannot choose an action (neither derive a policy `π`) only from a value function `V(s)` because, as you notice, it depends only on the state `s`.

The key concept that you are probably missing here, it's that TD(0) learning is an algorithm to compute the value function of a *given* policy. Thus, you are assuming that your agent is following a known policy. In the case of the Random Walk problem, the policy consists in choosing actions randomly.

If you want to be able to learn a policy, you need to estimate the action-value function `Q(s,a)`. There exists several methods to learn `Q(s,a)` based on Temporal-difference learning, such as for example SARSA and Q-learning.

In the Sutton's RL book, the authors distinguish between two kind of problems: *prediction* problems and *control* problems. The former refers to the process of estimating the value function of a given policy, and the latter to estimate policies (often by means of action-value functions). You can find a reference to these concepts in the [starting part of Chapter 6](http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/ebook/node60.html):

> As usual, we start by focusing on the policy evaluation or prediction
>   problem, that of estimating the value function for a given policy .
>   For the control problem (finding an optimal policy), DP, TD, and Monte
>   Carlo methods all use some variation of generalized policy iteration
>   (GPI). The differences in the methods are primarily differences in
>   their approaches to the prediction problem.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I thought that a policy `π` is just a function which gives for a given state the optimal action - but to do this I have to know al the values `Q`, so that the policy is not just the procedure "choose the best action" but also the internal mapping of (action, state) tuples to their value. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, not exactly, a policy `π` is a mapping from states to actions. Specifically, a policy `π` is a mapping from each state `s`, and action `a`, to the probability of taking the action `a` when the agent is the state `s`. An optimal policy is a policy that maximizes the reward obtained by the agent over the long run. An action-value function `Q` for a *given policy* estimates the long run reward obtained when taking action `a` in state `s`. Some methods, such as Q-learning, work by estimating the optimal `Q` function, and then deriving an optimal policy from it.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense to me now, too. Thank you! I just got one more question: I completed the example above know and was able to compute the theoretical expected values of `V` when using `gamma = 1.0`. But when I reduced gamma to 0.9 the distribution changed and I got the values `V =  0.063  0.144  0.262  0.431  0.694` - how can this be explained?

Comment: Great! :)  I don't know if I've understood correctly your question, but if the parameter `gamma` changes the value function should change also, right? Remember that the value function is defined as the expected return `R`, which depends on `gamma`. Then, it is expected a change in `V` when replacing `gamma = 1.0` by `gamma = 0.9`.

Comment: Uhm... is this so? I am a bit confused, because in Sutton's book in example 6.2 (see image above) it says, that the true values of the value function `V` can be computed to `1/6, 2/6, ...` without mentioning a value for `gamma`. Therefore, I thought, that `V` is independent of `gamma` and that `gamma` is just defining the speed with which the algorithm converges agains the true values.

Comment: Yes, it is. The example says the task is undiscounted, which implies `gamma = 1.0`. You need to understand the concept of return, both discounted and undiscounted (http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/ebook/node30.html) . Then, be sure you also understand the relation between returns and value functions (http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/ebook/node34.html). Lastly, the parameter that can be viewed as a way of controling the convergence speed is `alpha` (http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/ebook/node61.html <-- follow the link to Equation (2.5) in the second paragraph if necessary).